# Proving that two multiplicative functions are equal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

I need to prove the following statement:

"Let 'f' and 'g' be two multiplicative functions such that **f(p<sup>k</sup>) = g(p<sup>k</sup>)** for each prime **p** and **k $\geqslant$ 1**. Prove that f = g"

I have tried to approach this question by applying it for a particular number **n** with its prime factorization but couldn't figure how to even proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what does "multiplicative" mean to you?

Comment: f(mn) = f(m)f(n) when m and n are coprime

Comment: Ok...so if $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ what is $f(n)$?  What is $g(n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the prime factorization of $n$
$$
n=p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_k^{m_k}
$$
and proceed by recurrence over $k$.

Practically, if $k=0$, you have $n=1$ and the multiplicative functions should coincide to $1$. Having supposed that, for length $k$, they coincide, suppose now $n=p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}}$ and set $n'=p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_k^{m_k}$ (the product of the $k$ first terms) so that the last factor ($p_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}}$) is coprime with $n'$. By hypothesis we have  $f(n')=g(n')$ and then 
$$
f(n)=f(n')f(p_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}})=g(n')g(p_{k+1}^{m_{k+1}})=g(n)\ .
$$

Comment: How do prove the **functions** themselves to be equal?

Comment: @saisanjeev I will put more details

Comment: ohh induction.. thanks a lot @duchamp